# How to combine multiple dataframes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 data frames in my code...i need to combine all 3 into a single dataframe and save it in a excel sheet.
Attached the below 3 data frames, and i wanted to created the new data frame based on asset_id.

I tried as below:

```
import pickle
import os
frames = [a_dataframe, pandaDf, pandaDf1]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

It did not work...Can  someone pls help me

dataframe1:
[image]

dataframe 2:
[image]

Dataframe 3:
[image]

[image: I have used the below query...dataframe 2 and datframe 3 is not showig up]

output:
[image]

The final output after merging

```
final_df=pandaDf.append(pandaDf1, sort=True).merge(a_dataframe, on='asset_id')
final_df


final_df=pandaDf.append(pandaDf1, sort=True).merge(a_dataframe, on='asset_id')
final_df
final_df.head(10).to_dict()
```

[image: for analysis]

[image: after merging]

Comment: why did you put the `pyspark` tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the first 2 dataframes and then merge the 3rd dataframe, as follows:

```
final_df = df1.append(df2, sort=True).merge(df3, on='asset_id')
```

**Result:**

```
print(final_df)

   asset_id property_name  property_value  revision_id
0         1       HORIZON              24          314
1         1   GRANULARITY              24          314
2         2       HORIZON              48           12
3         2   GRANULARITY              24           12
4         3       HORIZON              24           24
5         3   GRANULARITY              24           24
6         4       HORIZON              24           43
7         4   GRANULARITY              48           43
```

### Edit

To further make `HORIZON` and `GRANULARITY` as column header and put their `property_value` under the columns, you can do a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), as follows:

```
final_df_pivoted = final_df.pivot(index=['asset_id', 'revision_id'], columns='property_name', values='property_value').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
print(final_df_pivoted)

   asset_id  revision_id  GRANULARITY  HORIZON
0         1          314           24       24
1         2           12           24       48
2         3           24           24       24
3         4           43           48       24
```

Comment: `/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:6211: FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.
sort=sort)

Comment: am getting above error..can u pls help me?

Comment: @Kanagambala  Ok, let me look at it

Comment: @Kanagambala  Edited my solution.  You can try again.

Comment: asset_id property_name_x property_value_x revision_id property_name_y property_value_y


@SeaBean i am getting output as above

Comment: @Kanagambala  Want to ensure we are talking with the same dataframe sequence.  `df1` refers to the one with `HORIZON` and `df2` refer to the one with `GRANULARITY` right ?  `df3` is the one with `revision_id`.   Is that right ?

Comment: yes...I wanted to combine everything based on asset_id

Comment: @Kanagambala  Let's split the 2 steps in my answer.  What's the result of `df1.append(df2, sort=True)` ?   Are there only 3 columns as in original df1 and df2 ?

Comment: @Kanagambala  Are you mixing up the codes by different solutions ?  My codes should not give you column labels like property_name_x  property_value_x  by adding suffix `_x` to the column name.  Such output should only happen when you merge 2 dataframe with same label of e.g. `property_name`    However, we only merge with `df3` which does not have column of  `property_name`.   Please check.  Thanks.

Comment: as u said.i have attched the code and output in the question section
final_df=a_dataframe.append(pandaDf, sort=True)

Comment: @SeaBEan..the issue is that in the dataframe 2..the value in the cell is Horizon and the header name property_name..But in the dataframe1...the property name by itself is revison id

Comment: @Kanagambala   Based on your screenshot of appending df1 and df2  I'm confused.  Just with df1 and df2, there should not have column of `revision_id` right ?    `revision_id` is in df3 which we still have not processed it

Comment: @Kanagambala   Make sure you are appending the 2 dataframes without the column `revision_id` and finally merge with the dataframe with `revision_id`.   Is that right ?

Comment: sorry i have appended the two dataframes and updated the snippet in question section..can u pls check

Comment: final_df=pandaDf.append(pandaDf1, sort=True).merge(a_dataframe, on='asset_id')
I used the above query to merge...but its throwing only headers

Comment: @Kanagambala  The screenshot looks good.  You can now merge with the df with the column `revision_id`  to arrive at the output I shown in my answer above.

Comment: -final_df=pandaDf.append(pandaDf1, sort=True).merge(a_dataframe, on='asset_id')

used as above..but its throwing..only headers as output
asset_id property_name property_value revision_id


Instead of property name..is it possible to get horizon and granuality

Comment: @Kanagambala  The codes looks good.  If you get empty result with only column headers, it means there is no match of `asset_id` during the merge.  You have to check whether there is really values of such `asset_id` appears in at `a_dataframe` and at least one of `pandaDf1` or `pandaDf`

Comment: @Kanagambala  Also make sure the data types of `asset_id` in all 3 dataframes are the same.  e.g. string type.

Comment: @SeaBEan...u r awesome! it worked...one question....instead of property name...is it possible to make granuality and horizon as headers?

Comment: @Kanagambala  Make sure you accept my solution. Not others.

Comment: @SeaBEanone question....instead of property name...is it possible to make granuality and horizon as headers?

Comment: @Kanagambala  In that case, you want the property-value under the horizon / granularity header ?

Comment: My header should be
asset_id Revision_id Granuality Horizon

Comment: @Kanagambala  Under Granuality Horizon  are their property_value, right ?

Comment: Yes..it should be like
 asset_id Revision_id Granuality Horizon
   1         4                      7             10

Comment: @Kanagambala  That will need a pivot.  I will edit the answer above.

Comment: Sure, pls @SeaBean

Comment: @Kanagambala  See my edit above.  Edited the additional requirement for you.

Comment: @SeaBEanfinal_df=pandaDf.append(pandaDf1, sort=True).merge(a_dataframe, on='asset_id')
final_df

final_df_pivoted = final_df.pivot(index=['asset_id', 'revision_id'], columns='property_name', values='property_value').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()

@SeaBean used code as above..
but facing error as 
ValueError: Length of passed values is 194, index implies 2

Comment: @Kanagambala  Is that a typo ?  There is an extra  final_df in  `final_df=pandaDf.append(pandaDf1, sort=True).merge(a_dataframe, on='asset_id') final_df`  ?

Comment: @SeaBEan...Yes its a typo..it should be

final_df=pandaDf.append(pandaDf1, sort=True).merge(a_dataframe, on='asset_id')

Comment: @Kanagambala  Can you show me a few lines of the merged result before pivot.  That is `final_df`

Comment: i have attached the snippet in my question section'

Comment: @Kanagambala  I mean the screenshot of resulting dataframe

Comment: @Kanagambala  Are you sure ?  I can only see the last picture as the append result.  Not the one after merge.

Comment: @SeaBEan..can u pls check now

Comment: @Kanagambala  Ok, see it now.  Thanks!  I see an extra column under Excel column E with all 1's there.  Is that what you get ?

Comment: @SeaBean...Actually that should be the revision id...Not sure y column name is mismatched...

I wanted Granuality and horizon as headers.. like you showed in your snippet

Comment: @Kanagambala  Probably you made some error in writing the dataframe to Excel / CSV.  The column labels were shifted.

Comment: @SeaBean....In Dataframe it seems to be correct...while am copying to excel it got mismatched i hope,..Is it possible to make granuality and horizon as header?

Comment: @Kanagambala  Yes, it can make them as header as my codes above.  I actually run the codes and got the result.

Comment: Do we need to import any package?

Comment: @Kanagambala  Can you dump a few lines of `final_df` for my investigation ?  By the code `final_df.head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: @Kanagambala  Please dump it for me to look at it and advise later.  Will come back after around 1 to 2 hours after some works.  Promise you, I will come back.

Comment: @Kanagambala  No extra package needed.

Comment: i am posting it in my question section...pls take a look into it...

Comment: final_df_pivoted = (final_df.set_index(["asset_id", "revision_id"])
        .pivot(columns="property_name")['property_value']
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
     )

Comment: The above code wokred..Thank u soo much for your help...U did not know u made my day

Comment: @Kanagambala That's great that you got it worked now.  Normally we don't need separate set_index before pivot.  That's why I think it maybe some data specific problem with your data.  Your data dump of to_dict() is also in screen dump rather than text.  It's hard to investigate based on that since we can't just copy and paste the data from screen dump.  It is the same reason your question got downvoted.  People here very much dislike screen dump data.  Bear in mind to post sample data as text next time if you want to get more  answers.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
a_dataframe['property_name'] = a_dataframe['property_name'].astype(str)
pandaDf['property_name'] = pandaDf['property_name'].astype(str)

a_dataframe['property_value'] = a_dataframe['property_value'].astype(int)
pandaDf['property_value'] = pandaDf['property_value'].astype(int)

final_df = a_dataframe.merge(pandaDf, on='asset_id', how='left')
final_df = final_df.merge(pandaDf1, on='asset_id', how='left')
```

in one line you can try this:

```
final_df = pandaDf1.merge(a_dataframe.merge(pandaDf,on='asset_id'),on='asset_id')
```

**EDIT** add code by request:

```
import pandas as pd
  
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3:4},
                   'p_value': {0: "HOR", 1: "HOR", 2: "HOR", 3:"HOR"}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3:4},
                   'p_value': {0: "GRAN", 1: "GRAN", 2: "GRAN", 3:"GRAN"}})


df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3:4},
                   'r_id': {0: "24", 1: "32", 2: "42", 3:"45"}})

final_df = df3.merge(df1.merge(df2, on='id'),on='id')
final_df
```

output:

```
id  r_id    p_value_x   p_value_y
0   1   24  HOR GRAN
1   2   32  HOR GRAN
2   3   42  HOR GRAN
3   4   45  HOR GRAN
```

Comment: @user1740577i haveused the above query...but dataframes are not combined..can u pls help me

Comment: @Kanagambala, what is your problem?

Comment: can you send this three-row of three dataframe

Comment: I have attached the output of the query.given by u..can u pls help mw

Comment: i need columns as asset_id, revision_id, Horizon, Granuality

Comment: @Kanagambala, I add a new code, try this, why do you get Nan value?

Comment: query returns only hearders...might be there is a problem with my data frame...can u help me in pivoting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236052/discussion-between-user1740577-and-kanagam-bala).

Answer (score 1):

Solution cited above by user1740577 seems to work.

I created directly the three dataframes in python and tried the solution cited and it worked. here's my code. Try to see if it works on your machine. If it doesn't, it might be the way of loading your excels into DataFrame which can cause an error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import IPython

df0 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 'HORIZON', 24], 
                     [2, 'HORIZON', 48], 
                     [3, 'HORIZON', 24],
                     [4, 'HORIZON', 24]], columns=['asset_id', 'property_name', 'property_value'])


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[3, 'GRANULARITY', 24],
                     [4, 'GRANULARITY', 48],
                     [1, 'GRANULARITY', 24],
                     [2, 'GRANULARITY', 24]], columns=['asset_id', 'property_name', 'property_value'])


df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[4, 24],
                     [2, 43],
                     [3, 314],
                     [1, 12]], columns=['asset_id','revision_id'])


print(df0)
print(df1)
print(df2)

final_df = df0.merge(df1, on='asset_id', how='left')
final_df = final_df.merge(df2, on='asset_id', how='left')

print(final_df)

IPython.embed()
```

Comment: df0 = a_dataframe, columns=['asset_id', 'property_name', 'property_value'])
df1 = pandaDf, columns=['asset_id', 'property_name', 'property_value'])
df2 = pandaDf1, columns=['asset_id','revision_id'])

I have edited the code as below...can u pls help me

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct, but what your data represent or how do you want to combine the dataframes is not clear. In the first dataframe "asset_id" 1 has "property name" 'HORIZON', but in the second dataframe the same "asset_id" has "property_name" 'GRANULARITY'. Confusing. And not possible to combine the dataframes nicely and logically.

Maybe renaming the columns with distinctive names could help in giving helpful and usable answers.